# Hyperledger Composer BNA deployment results in 'TCP write failed'

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I've followed the tutorial "Build your first network" for Hyperledger Fabric and added a CA. Now, when trying to deploy a BNA with composer, using `composer network deploy -a maintenance-network.bna -p maintenance -i PeerAdmin -s randomString -A admin -S`, i get an error:

```
~/network-setup$ composer network deploy -a ~/maintenance-
network/dist/maintenance-network.bna -p maint
enance -i PeerAdmin -s randomString -A admin -S
Deploying business network from archive: /home/vagrant/maintenance-
network/dist/maintenance-network.bna
Business network definition:
    Identifier: maintenance-network@0.1.11
    Description: Maintenance-network

✖ Deploying business network definition. This may take a minute...

Error: Error trying deploy. Error: Error trying install composer runtime. 
Error: TCP Write failed
Command failed
```

Does anyone know what the problem is ?

This is the output of `docker ps`:

```
IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                NAMES
2a4710a6805c        hyperledger/fabric-orderer   "orderer"                50 seconds ago      Up 48 seconds       0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                               orderer.example.com
81b8cab17323        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        50 seconds ago      Up 47 seconds       0.0.0.0:8051->8051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8053->8053/tcp       peer1.org1.example.com
ed8f0148a402        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        50 seconds ago      Up 48 seconds       0.0.0.0:9051->9051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9053->9053/tcp       peer0.org2.example.com
9de5f3918f1d        hyperledger/fabric-ca        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-..."   50 seconds ago      Up 47 seconds       0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                               ca_peerOrg1
d2d95dc6f20a        hyperledger/fabric-ca        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-..."   50 seconds ago      Up 48 seconds       7054/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8054->8054/tcp                     ca_peerOrg2
8396f528dc75        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        50 seconds ago      Up 48 seconds       0.0.0.0:10051->10051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10053->10053/tcp   peer1.org2.example.com
6b1185ea529a        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        50 seconds ago      Up 48 seconds       0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp       peer0.org1.example.com
```

This is the connection.json i'm using:

```
    {
"type": "hlfv1",
"orderers": [
   { "url" : "grpc://localhost:7050" }
],
"ca": { "url": "http://localhost:7054",
        "name": "ca-org1" 
},
"peers": [
        {
            "requestURL": "grpc://localhost:7051",
            "eventURL": "grpc://localhost:7053"
        },
        {
            "requestURL": "grpc://localhost:8051",
            "eventURL": "grpc://localhost:8053"
        },
        {
            "requestURL": "grpc://localhost:9051",
            "eventURL": "grpc://localhost:9053"
        },
        {
            "requestURL": "grpc://localhost:10051",
            "eventURL": "grpc://localhost:10053"
        }           
],
"keyValStore": "/home/vagrant/.composer-credentials",
"channel": "mychannel",
"mspID": "Org1MSP",
"timeout": "300"
}
```

The `keyValStore` contains the identity imported with:

```
composer identity import -p maintenance -u PeerAdmin -c crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem -k crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/*_sk
An identity was imported with name 'PeerAdmin' successfully
```

The docker containers are started with this `docker-compose-cli.yaml`:

```
version: '2'

networks:
  byfn:
services:
  ca0:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org1
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=false
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/CA1_PRIVATE_KEY
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/CA1_PRIVATE_KEY -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca_peerOrg1
    networks:
      - byfn

  ca1:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org2
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=false
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/CA2_PRIVATE_KEY
    ports:
      - "8054:8054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/CA2_PRIVATE_KEY -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca_peerOrg2
    networks:
      - byfn

  orderer.example.com:
    extends:
      file:   base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: orderer.example.com
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer0.org1.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer1.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer1.org1.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer0.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer0.org2.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer1.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file:  base/docker-compose-base.yaml
      service: peer1.org2.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools
    tty: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=false
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash -c './scripts/script.sh ${CHANNEL_NAME} ${DELAY}; sleep $TIMEOUT'
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
        - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
        - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
    depends_on:
      - ca0
      - ca1
      - orderer.example.com
      - peer0.org1.example.com
      - peer1.org1.example.com
      - peer0.org2.example.com
      - peer1.org2.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
```

And this is the output when running `CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml up -d`:

```
|  ____    _____      _      ____    _____
| / ___|  |_   _|    / \    |  _ \  |_   _|
| \___ \    | |     / _ \   | |_) |   | |
|  ___) |   | |    / ___ \  |  _ <    | |
| |____/    |_|   /_/   \_\ |_| \_\   |_|
|
| Starting the network
|
| Channel name : mychannel
| Creating channel...
| CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
| CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
| CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
| CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
| CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
| CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=false
| CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
| CORE_PEER_ID=cli
| CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
| CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.011 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.012 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.017 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 003 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.018 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 004 Returning existing local MSP
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.019 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 005 Obtaining default signing identity
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.019 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 006 Returning existing local MSP
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.019 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 007 Obtaining default signing identity
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.019 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 008 Sign: plaintext: 0AC6060A074F7267314D535012BA062D...53616D706C65436F6E736F727469756D
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.019 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 009 Sign: digest: D6E8392380793B24537309F14EA1C0D9CF3F18FF8292A65D09CF3AA92EA2094D
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.019 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 00a Returning existing local MSP
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.019 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 00b Obtaining default signing identity
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.019 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 00c Returning existing local MSP
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.019 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 00d Obtaining default signing identity
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.019 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 00e Sign: plaintext: 0AFD060A1508021A0608F892B0D00522...628AB20AD0563C9EA2A482A301EA32D8
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.019 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 00f Sign: digest: 5A58E17C75478098A108CFCFA1E909639C7830022602D225A61C4D0BE9E8C5AD
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.060 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 010 Returning existing local MSP
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.060 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 011 Obtaining default signing identity
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.060 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 012 Returning existing local MSP
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.060 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 013 Obtaining default signing identity
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.060 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 014 Sign: plaintext: 0AFD060A1508021A0608F892B0D00522...5B18D1838ED112080A021A0012021A00
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.060 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 015 Sign: digest: 4309C46AA7BBA47AD146AA77CB1ABAC79114C9C3D66D41B833F82ED7F882E326
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.082 UTC [channelCmd] readBlock -> DEBU 016 Received block: 0
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.083 UTC [main] main -> INFO 017 Exiting.....
| ===================== Channel "mychannel" is created successfully =====================
|
| Having all peers join the channel...
| CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
| CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
| CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
| CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
| CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
| CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=false
| CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
| CORE_PEER_ID=cli
| CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
| CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.121 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.121 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.123 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 003 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.123 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 004 Sign: plaintext: 0AC3070A5B08011A0B08F892B0D00510...A1A603DD33A31A080A000A000A000A00
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.123 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 005 Sign: digest: 5D870839DD3A368A48E2CED8314E3817CA48001BACBF74B36380408D851769AE
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.158 UTC [channelCmd] executeJoin -> INFO 006 Peer joined the channel!
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.158 UTC [main] main -> INFO 007 Exiting.....
| ===================== PEER0 joined on the channel "mychannel" =====================
| sleep: missing operand
| Try 'sleep --help' for more information.
|
| CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
| CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
| CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
| CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
| CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
| CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=false
| CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
| CORE_PEER_ID=cli
| CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
| CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:7051
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.194 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.194 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.196 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 003 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.196 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 004 Sign: plaintext: 0AC3070A5B08011A0B08F892B0D00510...A1A603DD33A31A080A000A000A000A00
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.196 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 005 Sign: digest: 0B0C3F308D78AC2FDD6FC89A71FED2DCB889038AE993980A6E4B540BB4D3C51A
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.248 UTC [channelCmd] executeJoin -> INFO 006 Peer joined the channel!
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.248 UTC [main] main -> INFO 007 Exiting.....
| ===================== PEER1 joined on the channel "mychannel" =====================
| sleep: missing operand
| Try 'sleep --help' for more information.
|
| CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt
| CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
| CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
| CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
| CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
| CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=false
| CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp
| CORE_PEER_ID=cli
| CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
| CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.288 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.288 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.289 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 003 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.290 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 004 Sign: plaintext: 0AC4070A5C08011A0C08F892B0D00510...A1A603DD33A31A080A000A000A000A00
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.290 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 005 Sign: digest: 992F4939F777DD575F2753ADF6936A7E6FB9CC8548C188B31E25B06F9ECEA7E7
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.335 UTC [channelCmd] executeJoin -> INFO 006 Peer joined the channel!
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.335 UTC [main] main -> INFO 007 Exiting.....
| ===================== PEER2 joined on the channel "mychannel" =====================
| sleep: missing operand
| Try 'sleep --help' for more information.
|
| CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt
| CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
| CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
| CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
| CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
| CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=false
| CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users/Admin@org2.example.com/msp
| CORE_PEER_ID=cli
| CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
| CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org2.example.com:7051
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.372 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.372 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.373 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 003 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.374 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 004 Sign: plaintext: 0AC4070A5C08011A0C08F892B0D00510...A1A603DD33A31A080A000A000A000A00
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.374 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 005 Sign: digest: 6776D313E8DD88880918868C6BA2C93ECEB05425FE93A7E385762918FA2AF556
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.419 UTC [channelCmd] executeJoin -> INFO 006 Peer joined the channel!
| 2017-11-15 09:31:36.419 UTC [main] main -> INFO 007 Exiting.....
| ===================== PEER3 joined on the channel "mychannel" =====================
| sleep: missing operand
| Try 'sleep --help' for more information.
|
|
| ========= All GOOD, BYFN execution completed ===========
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and Composer v0.14.2.

Comment: hi Eric -TCP write failed? what OS are you running on, what version?  This would help.  Also what version of Composer are you running with - looks like v0.14.x at a guess. Did you follow the prereqs at https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html? Just FYI we have just recently released v0.15.0 of Composer - it uses business network cards, I might suggest at some point to re-install with this latest level of code.

Comment: Hi Paul. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and Composer v0.14.2. I followed the prereqs, i'm able to deploy my bna without problems on the provided "hlfv1" chain. Now i wanted to try it with my own build network. 

I'm planning to update to v0.15.0, i haven't done it so far because it would break my automatisation scripts.

Answer (score 0):

So, if anyone has the same issue: There were errors in the mapping of the docker ports. The ports of the peer docker containers should be `7051` and `7053`, mapped to different ports on your host machine (e.g `8051`, `9051`, etc.).

Another error i found: I received the error `Error: Failed to deserialize creator identity, err expected MSP ID Org2MSP, received Org1MSP.` My peers at `7051` and `8051` have Org1MSP as MSP (Since they both belong to Org1), everyone else has Org2MSP. So, in the connection.json, you can't enter all peers at once. You have to create a connection.json for each MSP, with the peers connected to this MSP.