# failed deserializing event creator: [Expected MSP ID Org2MSP, received Org1MSP] while starting rest server in hyperledger

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have setup multichannel in fabric. I am using composer to execute transaction in fabric. 
I have 4 Channel in my network.Each channel contains 3 orgnization. When i am running network_setup.sh, it starts fabric network with all organization. However when i am running composer-rest-server, it gives me following error:

> 2018-01-06 09:32:32.278 UTC [eventhub_producer] Chat -> ERRO 14e1
>   error during Chat, stopping handler: rpc error: code = Canceled desc =
>   context canceled 2018-01-06 09:33:09.703 UTC [eventhub_producer]
>   validateEventMessage -> DEBU 14e2 ValidateEventMessage starts for
>   signed event 0xc4218f2a80 2018-01-06 09:33:09.703 UTC
>   [eventhub_producer] Chat -> ERRO 14e3 Error handling message: event
>   message must be properly signed by an identity from the same
>   organization as the peer: [failed deserializing event creator:
>   [Expected MSP ID Org2MSP, received Org1MSP]]

Can someone please help to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I think the clue is in the error you posted.  It says 'Expected MSP ID Org2MSP, received Org1MSP] ' - I suspect therefore that your connection profile information you created as part of your business network cards needs updating to reflect the right MSP - (you have built the appropriate card files and imported them, such as a PeerAdmin card ?)

As shown in the multi-org tutorial https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org.html you will need a profile for Org1 and a separate Org1 profile to include info from the 'other Orgs'(so will include info about their peers) on that channel / using the business network on that channel (ie whatever channel you've defined - 1 of 4 in our case) - then, further down the line, the same applies for each of the Orgs 1, 2 and 3). So your first port of call is to check your connection profile information in detail (the multi-org tutorial is a good starting point, showing how you connect up the peer information from the other org, 'org2' in org 1's profile -  particular for the `connection-org1.json`  sample profile (ie the 2nd profile shown in 'Step 3' of that tutorial).  which shows what's required for 'this Orgs' peer and the 'other member's peers' in your multi-org profile.. Other than that, it could be that Fabric crypto (cryptogen) configuration is not set up correctly for your custom multi-org setup.  See also the **answer** here for more information;
[Hyperledger Composer BNA deployment results in 'TCP write failed'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47304338/hyperledger-composer-bna-deployment-results-in-tcp-write-failed/47323452#47323452)

Comment: actually I am using composer version v0.13.2 . i have 5 orgnization

Comment: my two channel are working properly. when I try to start rest server for channel 3 organization 1 then its giving error . my connection profile is different for each organization in channel. i have checked my mapping in yaml files too. it seems correct.